# Google map API by location

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I have the property site where i need to show google map with  total counts of properties in one country and on click of it needs to open the each property seperately like property count for india is 45 then on click of 45 icon it will show seperate 45 peroperties and on click of each property needs to display the address of peroperty and the same will me be for all the other countries i have the multiple properties located in different countries.

guide me for the google map script.

thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to SO. You need to show a bit more effort to get an answer. A broad question without showing what you have tried goes against what this site is about.

Answer (score -1):

You can find a great guide here https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/basics